# install mongo with chef

Tags: mongodb, chef-infra

I've tried to figure out how to install a mongodb 3.4 instance using [this chef cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mongodb#readme). Nevertheless, I've not able to get to install it.

This is my `mongodb.rb` file content:

```
node.default['mongodb']['package_version'] = '3.4'
include_recipe 'mongodb::default'
```

And my `metadata.db`: `depends 'mongodb', '~> 0.16.2'`.

I've tried to verify it on centos-72 platform using `kitchen verify centos-72`. I'm getting this message:

> ERROR: yum_package[mongodb-org] (mongodb::install line 77) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Package: Version ["3.4"] of ["mongodb-org"] not found. Did you specify both version and release? (version-release, e.g. 1.84-10.fc6)

I'm realizing this cookbook tries to add this `yum_repository`:

```
yum_repository 'mongodb' do
    description 'mongodb RPM Repository'
    baseurl "http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/#{node['kernel']['machine']  =~ /x86_64/ ? 'x86_64' : 'i686'}"
    action :create
    gpgcheck false
    enabled true
  end
```

And according to this [mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/#install-mongodb-community-edition) the link repository should have to be:

```
https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/
```

instead of

```
"http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/..."
```

Comment: What error are you getting, what is your recipe ? Well [mcve].

Comment: Sorry @Tensibai. I've added some details.

Comment: what do you NOT understand in the error message ? it's crystal clear your version attribute doesn't match what Yum expect.

Comment: It seems to load an incorrect yum repository... Is it possible? Nevertheless, I don't quite figure out which exact version set...

Comment: you're using a very old cookbook, not updated since 2014... There's other cookbooks on supermarket, I don't use them so I can't tell for their quality, but there's chances they'll work better.

Answer (score 0):

The repo you are using does not have version 3.4 available. You can verify this manually by just looking at the RPMs in http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/RPMS/